# discord.js replace undefined popping up in a mention.users.first

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

So i have this command im working on for my bot and ive recently done a way for the bot to pick up mentions and add it to the bot's reply but i am wondering if there is a way for me to catch if no users have been mentioned and make it say something in replacement of "undefined"

```
expelliarmusRoles.forEach(findrole =>{
    if(message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === findrole)) hasRole = true; //if user has role, sets bool to true
})
if(hasRole === true){
  // store the first User object on the Map in variable mention
  var mention = message.mentions.users.first()
  var expell = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      if (expell < 50)
       message.reply(` ${mention} was hit by Expelliarmus and is disarmed.`)
      else if (expell < 70)
       message.reply(`The spell was blocked by ${mention}.`)
      else
      message.reply(`Your spell missed ${mention}.`)
  
}else{
  return message.say('Incorrect Year')
  
  }

}}
```

so if you mention anyone it will reply with " undefined was hit by Expelliarmus and is disarmed."
can i possibly catch it and be like "target dummy was hit by Expelliarmus and is disarmed." any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: why don't you just check whether `mention`'s value is `undefined` ? `${mention || "anonymous"}` could do the trick.

Comment: you know what that works...

Comment: Also you can simply use `if(hasRole)` instead of `if(hasRole === true)` just to make your code a bit cleaner.

Comment: ohh thanks for that pointer

Answer (score 0):

Just going to answer this question on robinvrd's behalf

why don't you just check whether mention's value is undefined ? ${mention || "anonymous"} could do the trick. – robinvrd